# Algebraic sub-extensions of an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Corollary 26, p. 232 in Lang starts as follows.

"Let $E$ be an extension of the field $k$ which is algebraically closed and let $k^a$ be the union of all sub extensions of $E$, which are algebraic over $k$."

My question is: why is $k^a$ non-empty?

Thanks.

Comment: Right! Thanks a lot. If you want write this as an answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: No problem. I'll post an answer to prevent Community bumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always one subextension of $E/k$ which is algebraic over $k$, namely $k$. But there will be others unless $k$ is already algebraically closed.